# React js modal with ExpansionPanelDetails with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui, react-bootstrap

This is the kind of effect I want to achieve:

[image]

This is the kind of effect I get:

[image]

As you can see from the image two Checkboxes go outside of the ExpansionPanelDetails and modal content.

Considering especially when the content needs to be resized.

I tried using Grid from @ material-ui / core, I tried using Col of react-bootstrap, but I couldn't find a solution.

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-elgamal-phjff)

Code modal:

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import {
  Checkbox,
  Divider,
  FormControl,
  FormControlLabel,
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel,
  Grid,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";

import ExpansionPanelDetails from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails";
import ExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";
import ExpansionPanelSummary from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

export default class CreateUserModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: true
    };
  }

  handleChange = panel => (event, isExpanded) => {
    this.setState({ expanded: isExpanded ? true : false });
  };

  checklist = () => {
    const { scopesList } = this.props;
    return scopesList.map((scope, i) => {
      let createChecked = true;
      let readChecked = true;
      let updateChecked = true;
      let deleteChecked = true;
      return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} xl={6} md={6} key={i}>
          <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth margin={"dense"}>
            <FormLabel component="label">
              <Typography>{scope}</Typography>
            </FormLabel>
            <FormGroup>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    color={"primary"}
                    checked={createChecked}
                    onChange={evt => this.onChangeScope(scope, "create", evt)}
                  />
                }
                label="Create"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    color={"primary"}
                    checked={readChecked}
                    onChange={evt => this.onChangeScope(scope, "read", evt)}
                  />
                }
                label="Read"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    color={"primary"}
                    checked={updateChecked}
                    onChange={evt => this.onChangeScope(scope, "update", evt)}
                  />
                }
                label="Update"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    color={"primary"}
                    checked={deleteChecked}
                    onChange={evt => this.onChangeScope(scope, "delete", evt)}
                  />
                }
                label="Delete"
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </FormControl>
          <Divider />
        </Grid>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { expanded } = this.state;
    const { show, onHide } = this.props;

    return (
      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={onHide}
        size="xl"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            Add New
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <ExpansionPanel
            expanded={expanded === true}
            onChange={this.handleChange("panel")}
          >
            <ExpansionPanelSummary
              expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
              id="panel1bh-header"
            >
              <Typography>Scopes</Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>{this.checklist()}</ExpansionPanelDetails>
          </ExpansionPanel>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>Footer</Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `row` class to `<ExpansionPanelDetails>`
[result](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-pine-c33mj)

Comment: I thank you, it seems to work.
But how could I make the internal checkboxes ie create, read, etc. of each permission form a square if the space permits.
By square I mean two above and two below.

Comment: change `<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} xl={6} md={6} key={i}>` to `<Grid item xs={6} sm={6} xl={6} md={6} key={i}>`

Comment: I don't see any change, I tried to put a grid inside a grid but it seems to work, but there is a moment when you resize that on one side to the left there are three checkboxes on the right only one: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lovelace-uwgz1

Comment: i dont see any strange behaviour

Comment: At some point this happens to a certain extent: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMbmX.png

Comment: So what I would like if I can find a way would be when the size is maximum is allow it.
then put all 4 checkboxes in a single line, when it is reduced and the space is no longer available then divide it into a pair of two.
two above and two below.
when there is no space available for this, then put them on top of each other.
Do you think it is possible to do such a thing?

Comment: try something like  `<Grid item xs={12} sm={6} xl={6} md={3} key={i}>`